# nginx rewrite rule for trailing slash to load fpm/wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

Currently, i have nginx/php-fpm setup in a docker container and the wordpress folder mounted as a volume in the container. I want xyz.com/blog and xyz.com/blog/ both function exactly the same.
I have the following nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        server_name  0.0.0.0;
        root         /mnt/blog;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    location / {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last; #converted from .htaccess
        }
    }
    location ~ .php$ {

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

While hitting `xyz.com/blog/` - the wordpress site gets loaded as expected but when i remove the trailing slash(/) - `xyz.com/blog`, i get `301 Moved Permanently` error. How can i ensure that that both `xyz.com/blog` and `xyz.com/blog/` behave correctly and load the wordpress site?

Answer (score 0):

You want `/blog` to invoke `/index.php` without first redirecting to `/blog/`.

Based on your existing solution you could change the `if (!-e ...` to `if (!-f ...`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) for details.

However, the same functionality can be achieved with:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried the following :
            location = /blog {
            if (!-f $request_filename){
                rewrite ^(.*)$ $1/index.php break;
            }
        }

The problem now is that index.php is now loaded as a html file rather that processed by fastcgi/fpm.

Comment: I also tried: `location = /blog {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }`
But i get a 301 error - permanently moved.